# SQL Server INNER JOIN multiple inner joins with multiple relations

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have the following query.  It works just fine but I need to pull the BUserName from another table named FB that has a UserID field that is related to the UserID in the FU table.  Is this possible?

```
    SELECT TOP 100 
    FF.XID, 
    FF.YID, 
    FF.Title, 
    FF.FileName, 
    FF.FilePath, 
    FU.UserName as FUUserName, 
    FU.UserName as BUserName
    FROM FF 
    INNER JOIN FU ON FU.UserID = FF.UserID
```

Just to clarify. I dont have a UserName column in the FB table. It does have FB.UserID which has a relation to FF.UserID which is where I want to pull the second UserName from. So with that relation I am trying to pull the username down from the FF.UserID table that is related to the userID in the FB table. Does this make any sense?

Comment: Yes, you just need to add anoter inner join. Please post your table structure as create table statements as well.

Comment: Is the FU.UserName showing up twice as different aliases a typo?

Comment: Ill have to get the table info once I get off of work.

Comment: I dont have a BUserName column in the FB table. It does have FB.UserID which has a relation to FF.UserID. So with that relation I am trying to pull the username down from the FF.UserID table that is related to the userID in the FB table. Does this make any sense?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 100 
FF.XID, 
FF.YID, 
FF.Title, 
FF.FileName, 
FF.FilePath, 
FU.UserName as FUUserName, 
FU.UserName as BUserName,
FB.BUserName as FB_BUserName
FROM FF 
    INNER JOIN FU ON FU.UserID = FF.UserID 
    INNER JOIN FB ON FB.UserID = FU.UserID
```

Now, `FF` ties to `FU`, which then ties to `FB`. As they are all inner joined, you can use the law of association to understand that this acts like they are all linked together.

```
 FF = FU   FU = FB    Therefore FF = FB
```

Comment: Justin, I dont have a BUserName column in the FB table.  It does have FB.UserID which has a relation to FF.UserID. So with that relation I am trying to pull the username down from the FF.UserID table that is related to the userID in the FB table. Does this make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

Like that?

```
SELECT TOP 100  
    FF.XID,  
    FF.YID,  
    FF.Title,  
    FF.FileName,  
    FF.FilePath,  
    FU.UserName as FUUserName,  
    FU.UserName as BUserName,
    FB.BUserName  
    FROM FF  
    INNER JOIN FU ON FU.UserID = FF.UserID  
    INNER JOIN FB ON FU.UserID = FB.UserID
```

Comment: This might be confusing as you have two columns of the same name. One of the columns should be (re)-aliased

Comment: But there is no information in the question does he need both of those fields in output or he want to rename one of them. And it looks like he can rename it by himself.

Comment: OK, just thought it might be a nicety to change, but it is your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 100 
FF.XID, 
FF.YID, 
FF.Title, 
FF.FileName, 
FF.FilePath, 
FU.UserName as FUUserName, 
FB.UserName as BUserName
FROM FF 
INNER JOIN FU ON FU.UserID = FF.UserID 
INNER JOIN FB ON FU.UserID = FB.UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT TOP 100 
    FF.XID, 
    FF.YID, 
    FF.Title, 
    FF.FileName, 
    FF.FilePath, 
    FU.UserName as FUUserName, 
    FB.BUserName
    FROM FF 
    INNER JOIN FU ON FU.UserID = FF.UserID 
    INNER JOIN FB ON FB.UserID = FU.UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

***Another two example***

**1- with null result:**

```
use my_DB
SELECT tbl_users.UserName
,Updated.UserName   /*Updated not in tbl*/

FROM [my_DB].[dbo].[my_tbl]
left outer join  tbl_users ON tbl_users.UserID = my_tbl.UserID
left outer join tbl_users Updated ON tbl_users.UserID = my_tbl.LasUpdatedUserID
```

**2- with out null result:**

```
SELECT tbl_users.UserName
,Updated.UserName   /*Updated not in tbl*/
FROM [my_DB].[dbo].[my_tbl]
INNER JOIN  tbl_users ON tbl_users.UserID = my_tbl.UserID
INNER JOIN tbl_users Updated ON tbl_users.UserID = my_tbl.LasUpdatedUserID
```

**