# SQL puzzle very close to solving but can't get parentid

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I need a bit of help/direction as to how to write an SQL query using the following information:

[image: Please click here for the SQL table]

The Question is:

The manager would like to see all of the cars currently in the showroom and their price, in the following form: [Make] [Model] – £[Price] e.g. “VW GOLF - 3000”. Write a SQL query to satisfy this.

I can't seem to get the parentCarid to match the ID in the car table and this is the closest ive gotten to making it happen.

```
SELECT  Car.Makecode, Car.Name, Showroom.Price
FROM Car
INNER JOIN Showroom
ON Car.Id=Showroom.CarID
WHERE Showroom.CarId = “2” OR Showroom.CarId = “5” OR Showroom.CarId = “8”;
```

But this still doesn't display the Model name it only displays model code and I'm thinking i would need to somehow join the Car table with itself to get the answer.

So I want to display it like this in a way :

```
Model    Make     Price

Ford Fiesta   - 4000    
VW  Golf     - 3000    
Peugeot 307   -5000
```

Comment: If you explain or give me the Query i can try and see if it works but yes it might be easier

Comment: I am using something similar so i can test it out immediately so let me know

Comment: Okay i am on sql fiddle how do i add my tables onto it ?

Comment: Thanks and let me know

Comment: Your answer works now in the fiddle thank you Ryan

Comment: Yea i mean more detail is better for me since it helps me in understanding and yea sure ill give you more detail when asking next time

Comment: I combination of all since every answer has something which i can implement to my initial one

Comment: I decided to `get a list of cars by manufacturer` and then join that to the `showroom`. [Is just how I thought about the requirements](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19986/3). Alas, Not the the most efficient - was fun to do. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this query:

```
SELECT c.Id, p.Name, c.Name, s.Price
FROM Car c 
     INNER JOIN Car p ON p.Id = c.ParentCarId
     INNER JOIN Showroom s ON s.CarId = c.Id
```

Comment: Okay give me a minute to try this, but where does the p in p.makecode come from ?

Comment: I tried it and it displays the Makecode not the actual make which is the same as my solution, so it displays

For Fiesta - 4000

Comment: So you want the name of the maker, not the make code? That is, you want Ford Fiesta - 4000?

Comment: Yes so i want it like this :

2 Ford Fiesta - 4000

Comment: It doesn't work and this is the error i get :

Result was: SQL command contained errors. Check, correct and try again
Error description: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(p.Id = c.ParentCarId) 
     INNER JOIN Showroom s ON (s.CarId = c.Id)'.
-- Operation concluded at 16:14:05--

Comment: I removed the parentheses and still doesn't work, this is what i entered:

SELECT c.Id, c.Name, p.MakeCode, s.Price
FROM Car c 
     INNER JOIN Car p ON p.Id = c.ParentCarId
     INNER JOIN Showroom s ON s.CarId = c.Id

Comment: If you are using Microsoft SQL Server that is the correct syntax for JOIN, see for instance [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9834596/2382734).

Comment: Still says missing operator

Comment: 'SELECT Make.Name, Model.Name,'-', '£',S.Price FROM car Make
    JOIN car Model ON Make.id = Model.parentCarID
    JOIN showroom S ON Model.ID = S.CarID'
 
Can you think i can simplify this or yours since i want to add the £ sign and the '-' to it

Answer (score 0):

You could add another INNER JOIN with Car Table ON the ParentCarID.

```
SELECT PC.Name, Car.Name, Showroom.Price
FROM Car
INNER JOIN Car PC 
   ON PC.ID = Car.ParentCarID
INNER JOIN Showroom
   ON Car.Id=Showroom.CarID
```

Comment: This is what i got :Result was: SQL command contained errors. Check, correct and try again
Error description: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'PC.ID = Car.ParentCarI
INNER JOIN Showroom
   ON Car.Id=Showroom.CarID'.
-- Operation concluded at 16:21:18--

Comment: There is a missing **D** in your query  expression
    'PC.ID = Car.ParentCarI**D** INNER

Comment: Do not use any quotes.